# The Dot Product

Tags: vectors

I'm sure this is pretty basic and has been answered before but I couldn't find any satisfactory answer. Purely for the purpose of understanding a geometric representation of the dot product could someone show me why $A \cdot B  > A \cos \theta$. Essentially why is $A \cos \theta$ not the projection? A diagram with the two of them would be nice.

Comment: $\vec{A} . \vec{B}=|\vec{A}|  |\vec{B}| \cos\theta$

Comment: Yes I understand that, but why isn't A cos theta enough? Why multiply by the other vector's magnitude?

Comment: To follow up from the comment, it IS the projection if the direction vector has magnitude $1$.

Comment: Like how does multiplying by B's magnitude affect the visual representation?

Comment: I think the problem that you're having here is that you've seen the visual representation only with $\|B\| = 1$, and that's become your understanding of the concept. There's two ways to define the dot product: algebraically as a sum of products of coordinates, or geometrically, as $\|A\| \|B\| \cos(\theta)$. In the latter case, we are done. In the former case, it's worth noting that the definition depends heavily on the magnitude of $B$ (e.g. if $B$ were twice as long, the dot product would be twice as large). I'm not certain what more there can be said on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From law of cosines we know that $||A - B||^2 = ||A||^2+||B||^2 -2||A||||B||\cos (\theta)$

From this it follows that $||A||||B||\cos (\theta) =\frac{||A||^2+||B||^2-||A-B||^2}{2} = \frac{A\cdot A + B\cdot B-(A-B)\cdot(A-B)}{2} = \frac{A\cdot A+B\cdot B-A\cdot A+A\cdot B + B\cdot A - B \cdot B}{2} = \frac{2A \cdot B}{2} =  A \cdot B$

So overall, $||A|| ||B|| \cos (\theta) = A \cdot B$

Does this answer your question? The geometric intuition comes from law of cosines.

Comment: The third side of a triangle is $||A-B||$. That explains the wrong sign you get. Good answer, anyway.

Comment: It's late and I'm tired :) Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for taking $A\cdot B$ to be $|A||B|\cos\theta$ and not just $|A|\cos\theta$ is not geometric, but algebraic: although the projection is more intuitive in a visual sense, the actual definition produces a symmetric product, which does not gives preference to one of the vectors over the other, and so is more suitable when making computations.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the dot product of two vectors $A = [a, b, c]$ and $B = [d, e, f]$ is $A\cdot B = ad + be + cf$. Or, the sum of each component sequentially multiplied together.

Note that $A\cdot B = |A||B|\cos(\theta)$ follows from the definition (and vice versa), so this is also a definition. This ends up being the area of the parallelogram that the vectors create, so this is yet another way to define the dot product.

You have noticed that one vector's projection onto a line is given by $|A|\cos(\theta)$. Another way to write that using the dot product is $\frac{A\cdot B}{|B|}$ by rearranging the definition of the dot product.

Comment: What's the difference between projecting it onto a line and onto another vector, B?

Comment: Doesn't it always tend to visually form a 90  degree angle?

Comment: There isn't a difference. Just, if you want to write it in terms of the dot product, you'll need to take the length of the direction vector into account.